# why if($row['field'] == value) work like SELECT WHERE field = value?

Tags: php, mysql

Today I'm drunked. I write wrong code like this.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, status FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      if($row['status'] == 'Active') {
         echo "<br> id: ". $row["id"]. " - Name: ". $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"] . "<br>";
     } 
}
```

and it work like SELECT WHERE status = 'Active'  .
It not make sense for me why is it work?

I think if statement just check the one column, and not relative to that all row column. It should not work.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: why is it work?

Comment: You are fetching all the records from your database table...all of them...then in your `while` loop, you are checking row by row, if some of the fields match a certain condition...if so, you print the result...but like I said before, you are looping through all of your records(row by row, aye aye!)

Comment: I think your question is why `$row['status'] == 'Active'` works when you're not retrieving the status column. Is that correct?

Comment: I think if statement just check the one column, and not relative to that all row column.  It should not work.

Comment: Ah, then it's working exactly as it should. You can do the comparison in either Sql or PHP. If you do it in SQL, you'll only get those rows. If you do it in PHP, you'll retrieve all of the rows, and then only echo out those based on your IF. Retreiving all the rows like this is useful if you want to change the format based on the status.

Comment: This is why you shouldn't write code while drunked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is:

1. `if($row['status'] == 'Active') {` Here you bring all table records from the db to your app, and do the filter on the client side. So this have a performance  cost in transporting all the data.
2. `WHERE status= 'Active'` Do the filter in the db, and only send the relevant data, so is more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

They both are used in php.

`==`    Equality    `$x == $y`  Returns `true` if $x and $y have the same key/value pairs.

`===`   Identity    `$x === $y` Returns `true` if $x and $y have the same key/value pairs in the same order and of the same types.

I hope your doubt is cleared now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The sintax for equal  operator in PHP  is ==     (or ===)

like in  your code

```
if($row['status'] == 'Active')
```

the sintax for equal  operator in mysql (or sql) is =

like

```
 SELECT WHERE col1 = 'Active' .
```

so the result is equivalent